# Bipartite graph $G=(V,E)$ with parts $X$ and $Y$ satisfying $|\Gamma(S)| \geq \frac{|S|}{2}$ for any subset $S \subseteq X$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

> Prove that for a bipartite graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V = X \cup Y$, if for any subset $S \subseteq X$ we have $|\Gamma(S)| \geq \frac{|S|}{2}$, then there is a subgraph $H=(V,E^\prime)$ such that $d_H(x)=1$ for all $x \in X$ and $d_H(y) \leq 2$ for all $y \in Y$.

Here $\Gamma(S)$ is the set of neighbours of $S$, i.e. the union of neighbours of each $x$ in $S$.

I think it can be proven by induction. First, we observe that if $d(v) \leq 2$ for all $v \in Y$, then we can obtain the desired subgraph by throwing edges until every vertex in $X$ is degree of 1. The assumption assures that $d(x)$ is at least 1 for each $x\in X$. After that I assume that there is a vertex $y\in Y$ with $d(y) \geq 2$. I have tried couple more things after this as removing two vertices joining $y$ in X with minimum degree, etc. But it did not lead me anywhere. I would appreciate if you give me any hint!

Another attempt to solve the problem:

I read the proof of Hall's marriage theorem and tried to adopt this question to that proof.

So I want to check the following three cases:

1. If for every $S\subseteq X$, $|\Gamma(S)| \geq \frac{|S|}{2}+1$,
2. If there exists a subset $S$ of $X$ such that $|\Gamma(S)|=\frac{|S|}{2}$,
3. If there exists a subset $S \subset X$ such that $|\Gamma(S)|=\frac{|S|+1}{2}$.

I have proved that desired subgraph exists for the first and second cases but not for the third one. I would really really appreciate if you help me!

Comment: So there is a general trick that can be used with hall's theorem, which is to find some auxiliary graph (usually hard to spot...) which satisfies hall's theorem, and then this matching corresponds to what you want in your original graph (in some way). So you could try to do that if you like.

Comment: Should I try this trick to the general problem or to the 3rd case?

Comment: I got it! Thank you =)

Comment: Aha sorry I forgot to respond, no worries! It's an excellent trick, it can produce arguments just as pleasant (and hard to see how they were thought of) as ones via pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final answer if anyone is interested:

It is obvious that if $d(v) \leq 2$ for every $v \in Y$, then we can obtain the desired subgraph by throwing edges until every vertex $x$ in X is degree of 1. Therefore, in the rest of the proof we will assume that there exists a vertex $v \in Y$ with $d(v) >2$.

We will prove this question by induction on $|X|$. If $|X|=1$, let's say $X=\{x\}$, then $d(x)=|\Gamma(x)|\geq \frac{1}{2}$. Then just pick one of the neighbours of $X$ and consider that edge as the desired subgraph, so we are done. Now suppose for every subset $S \subseteq X$, $S \neq \emptyset,X$ we have $|\Gamma(S)| \geq \frac{|S|}{2}+1.$ Choose $x_1,x_2 \in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $y \in \Gamma(x_1) \cap \Gamma(x_2)$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the vertices with minimum degree among all $x \in X$ with $y \in \Gamma(x)$. This ensures that when we remove these vertices, there is no vertex in $X$ of degree 0. It is obvious from the assumption that we cannot have 3 vertices in $X$ with degree 1 and all are joined to the same vertex in $Y$. Once we remove these vertices, we obtain the induced graph $G_0 = G[V-\{x_1,x_2,y\}]$ with parts $X_1$ and $Y_1$ where $X_1=X-\{x_1,x_2\}$ and $Y_1=Y-\{y_1\}.$ For any $T \subseteq X_1$,

$\Gamma_{G_0}(T) = \Gamma_G(T)-\{y\}$ then $|\Gamma_{G_0}(T)| \geq |\Gamma_G(T)|-1 \geq \frac{|T|}{2}$.

So there is a subgraph $H_0$ of $G_0$ satisfying the desired conditions. Adding the vertices $x_1,x_2,y$ and the edges $x_1y,x_2y$ gives the desired subgraph in G.

Now suppose there exists $S \subseteq X$, $S \neq \emptyset , X$ with $|\Gamma(S)|= \frac{|S|}{2}$. Then let $X_1=S$ and $Y_1=N(S)$, and $X_2= X-X_1$ and $Y_2 = Y-Y_1$. Consider $G_1=G[X_1 \cup Y_1]$ and $G_2=G[X_2 \cup Y_2]$.

For any $T \subseteq X_1$, $\Gamma_{G_1}(T)=\Gamma_G(T)$ then $|\Gamma_{G_1}(T)|=|\Gamma_G(T)| \geq \frac{|T|}{2}$.

For any $T \subseteq X_2$, $\Gamma_{G_2}(T)=\Gamma_G(T) - N(S)= \Gamma_G(T \cup S) - N(S)$, then $|\Gamma_{G_2}(T)| \geq |\Gamma_G(T \cup S)|- |N(S)| \geq \frac{|T|+|S|}{2}-\frac{|S|}{2}= \frac{|T|}{2}$.

These prove that there are subgraphs in $G_1$ and $G_2$ with the desired conditions. Hence, their union gives the desired subgraph in $G$.

Finally, suppose if there exists $S \subseteq X$, $S \neq \emptyset , X$ with $|\Gamma(S)| = \frac{|S|+1}{2}$. Let $X_1=S$ and $Y_1=N(S)$, and $X_2= X-X_1$ and $Y_2 = Y-Y_1$ and consider $G_1=G[X_1 \cup Y_1]$ and $G_2=G[X_2 \cup Y_2]$. It is similar to the previous case to show that $G_1$ has a subgraph with desired conditions.

Now we obtain a new graph $G_2^\prime $ by adding vertices $u_1$ and $u_2$ to $X_2$ and $v$ to $Y_2$, respectively and edges $xv$ for every $x \in X_2$ as well as $u_1$ and $u_2$.  Observe that $d(u_i)=1$ for $i=1,2$ and $y$ is contained in every neighbour set.

For any $T \subseteq X_2 \cup \{u_1,u_2\}$, $\Gamma_{G_2^\prime}(T) = \Gamma_G(T) \cup \{v\} - \Gamma(S) = \Gamma_G(T \cup S) \cup \{v\} - \Gamma(S)$. Then

$|\Gamma_{G_2^\prime}(T)| \geq |\Gamma(T \cup S) \cup \{v\}| - |\Gamma(S)| \geq \frac{|T|+|S|}{2}+1 - \frac{|S|+1}{2} \geq \frac{|T|}{2}.$

This shows that we have a subgraph in $G_2^\prime$ with desired conditions, and by removing $u_1,u_2$ and $v$ we obtain a subgraph in $G_2$ with desired conditions.

Similarly, the union of the subgraphs found in $G_1$ and $G_2$ is a subgraph in $G$ with the desired conditions.

This completes the proof.